# How to change date/time in time series txt file?

Tags: powershell

I need to reformat a time series dataset that is stored in a .txt file:

1. I need to shift the time shown by one minute backwards, and
2. I need to add a ';' to the end of each row.

It would be preferable to carry out both formatting steps for each row together as the files are quite big. Here I show a before and after example:

```
2013/09/30;235800;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1
2013/09/30;235900;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;0
2013/10/01;000000;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;2
2013/10/01;000100;1.3527;1.3527;1.3527;1.3527;20
```

Notice how there is a further wrinkle at midnight because the time and date have to take a step back.

```
2013/09/30;235700;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1;
2013/09/30;235800;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;0;
2013/09/30;235900;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;1.3526;2;
2013/10/01;000000;1.3527;1.3527;1.3527;1.3527;20;
```

Comment: Being new doesn't mean you don't have to at least try. Good starting points would be [`Import-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx), the [`PowerShell tip on working with date/time values`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730960.aspx), and [`ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Static methods from .Net classes can be used in PowerShell like this: `[name.space.class]::Method()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer a shorter version using `[DateTime]::ParseExact()` and the `[String].SubString()` method.

```
gc $FilePath|%{
    $datetime = $_.substring(0,17).replace(";"," ")
    $newdate=[datetime]::ParseExact($datetime,"yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss",$null).AddMinutes(-1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss").replace(" ",";")
    "$newdate;$($_.substring(18,($_.length-18)));"
}|Out-File $NewFilePath
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
      [string] $row)

begin
{
    [string[]] $newRows = @()
}
process
{ 
    $items = $row.Split(";")

    $date = $items[0] 

    $times = [regex]::Matches($items[1], "(\d\d)")

    [string] $cTime = $("{0}:{1}:{2}" -f $times.value)

    [datetime] $currentTime = $("{0} {1}" -f $date, $cTime)

    Write-Verbose $("Current Time: {0}" -f $currentTime)

    [datetime] $newTime = $currentTime.AddMinutes(-1)

    Write-Verbose $("NewTime: {0}" -f $newTime)

    $items[0] = $newTime.ToShortDateString()

    $items[1] = $("{0:D2}{1:D2}{2:D2}" -f $newTime.Hour, $newTime.Minute, $newTime.Second)

    [string] $newRow = ""

    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        $newRow += "{0};" -f $item
    }

    $newRows += $newRow

}

end
{
    Write-Output $newRows
}
```